# How to add multiple input field inside a div dynamically using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create some multiple input field dynamically on `onkeypress` event using JavaScript/jQuery.

I have one text-box,when user is entering any key on that text area two input field and second text-box is opening. When user will enter any key on second text box again another two input field and third text-box will open and so on. There is also a cross button is creating to close each individual set of text-box. In my current code I doing this putting all field static as user may create many numbers of input field so that I want to create those in dynamically with different `name and id`.

My code is [in this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PLwzb4ZwnZaZeNq34wLP?p=preview).

Comment: Do post necessary code in the post as well...

Comment: [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks like this question has been abandoned, and left in a somewhat uncertain state. I don't know if there is much value in maintaining this question, I wonder if it should be put on hold? Satya: the author of the larger answer below says in your chat that the code worked. If you can remember whether it worked for you, you might consider accepting the answer, on the basis of their evident effort.

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT: Misunderstood question, answer below

This can easily be done if you have a specific field in which to create the input fields. For example, I will load input fields into `document.body`

Everytime you call `newinput()` an input field is created in `parent` who's `id` starts at `input0` and increments each time

```js
var id = 0;
var newinput = function() {
  var parent = document.body
  var field = document.createElement("input")
  field.className = "myclassname"
  field.style = "display:block;"
  field.id = "input" + id;
  parent.appendChild(field);
  id += 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Click plus to add input</div>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="newinput()">+</button>
</body>
```

In your case, it looks like you want to add a group, you can do this:

```
var fieldgroup = document.querySelector(".questionshowp .form-group").cloneNode(true); // (1)

var addinput = function(){
    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; // (2)
    var n = parent.querySelectorAll(".form-control").length 
    var f = fieldgroup.cloneNode(true);
    f.children[0].id = "question"+n // (3)
    f.querySelector(".secondsec").querySelector("button.btn-success").onclick = addinput // (4)
    parent.insertBefore(f,parent.querySelector(".clear")); // (5)
}
```

1. Create a copy of a `field-group` to be used as a template
2. Get the container of input fields
3. Set the input field `id` with regard to total number of form-groups in parent
4. Make sure template applies `addinput()` to button
5. Insert input form before end of parent form

The easiest way apply this function to all `+` buttons is with JQuery

```
$("button.btn-sm.btn-success").on("click", addinput)
```

This would **need** to be located at the bottom of your html file, and below `addinput()` definition

## EDIT: Real Answer

Turns out I wrote all that and just realized I misunderstood your question.
Still we can use the same principle to do what I believe you are asking

```
master = document.querySelector(".aquestionpart"); // (1)
form = document.querySelector(".questionparts"); // (2)

function show(){
    var f = form.cloneNode(true);
    var n = master.querySelectorAll(".questionparts").length;
    f.id = "questionparts"+(n+1); // (3)
    f.querySelector("#questions").onkeypress = show; // (4)
    this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#questionparts"+ n + " > .questionshowp").style ="display:block;"; // (5)
    this.onkeypress = undefined; // (6)

    master.insertBefore(f,master.children[master.children.length-1]) // (7)
}
form.querySelector("#questions").onkeypress = show; // (8)
form = form.cloneNode(true); // (9)
```

1. Get poll container
2. Get poll question form to use as template
3. Set new poll question form `id` with respect to number of others
4. Set show function to new poll question
5. Show multiple choice
6. Make sure subsequent keypresses dont create more questions
7. Insert question before `.clear`
8. sets up first question to show
9. creates copy of fresh question to use as template

With this your current scripts.js is unnecessary, and `.aquestionpart` must look like this for proper formatting

```
<div class="aquestionpart">
    <div class="questionparts" id="questionparts1">...</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

From within `.questionparts` be sure to remove `onkeypress="show();"` from `input`. It should look like this.

```
<input name="questions" id="questions" class="form-control" placeholder="Questions" value="" type="text">
```

And **finally** an interesting note is that both of the scripts I've provided can be used together! (With some slight modifications)

```
//Author: Shane Mendez
var fieldgroup = document.querySelector(".questionshowp .form-group").cloneNode(true);
var addinput = function(){
    var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var n = parent.querySelectorAll(".form-control").length 
    var f = fieldgroup.cloneNode(true);
    f.children[0].id = "question"+n 
    f.querySelector(".secondsec").querySelector("button.btn-success").onclick = addinput 
    console.log(parent)
    parent.insertBefore(f,parent.children[parent.children.length-1]);
}

master = document.querySelector(".aquestionpart");
form = document.querySelector(".questionparts");

function show(){
    var f = form.cloneNode(true);
    var n = master.querySelectorAll(".questionparts").length;
    f.id = "questionparts"+(n+1);
    f.querySelector("#questions").onkeypress = show;
    console.log(this)
    this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("#questionparts"+ n + " > .questionshowp").style ="display:block;";
    this.onkeypress = undefined;
    master.insertBefore(f,master.children[master.children.length-1])
    $(f.querySelectorAll("button.btn-sm.btn-success")).on("click", addinput)
}
form.querySelector("#questions").onkeypress = show;
form = form.cloneNode(true);
$("button.btn-sm.btn-success").on("click", addinput)
```

If you put this in your scripts.js file and put that at the bottom of your `body` tag, then the only thing left is the `-` buttons.

Comment: @ Shane Abram Mendez : Ok,I am implementing your code and let you know.

Comment: I have implemented your code but its not working. Here is my current [https://plnkr.co/edit/Y1oGMC5loG6gKDYEAnm7] plunkr and this is my (previous)[https://plnkr.co/edit/PLwzb4ZwnZaZeNq34wLP?p=preview] plunkr. Please check this.

Comment: There is nothing in the new one.

Comment: `.questionparts` has to contain `.questionshowp` with all desired initial fields. Basically the first form has to be created by you.

Comment: i have to create dynamic all those because user may create nos of question.

Comment: The user may not create a question at all? How do you intend to show the question field in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115366/discussion-between-satya-and-shane-abram-mendez).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Press](https://www.adminspress.com/onex/view/uaomui) to add multiple input field inside a div dynamically using jQuery. Here you only need to call the function that takes two parameter `HTMLElement` and `config` like:

```
  $(".addInput").click(function() {
    build_inputs($(this), config);
  });
```

In the config you can add numbers of inputs form config like:

```
let config = {
  title: "Slides",
  forms: [
    {
      type: "text",
      name: "name",
      class: "form-control mb-2",
      placeholder: "Enter Data..."
    },
    {
      type: "file",
      name: "image",
      class: "btn btn-light btn-sm mb-2 btn-block"
    },
    {
      type: "number",
      name: "mobile",
      class: "form-control mb-2",
      placeholder: "Enter Data..."
    }
  ],
  exportTo:$('#getData')
};
```